# NSFetchedResultsController not Detecting type of Change When an Object is Inserted or Updated

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a collectionView. The second section of the collection is populated by an NSFetchedResultsController. The cells are populated by the Recipients object. On a different viewController I add a video to core data. the video is a relationship to the Recipients Object. It is a one to many relationship. One Recipient can have many videos, but each video can only have one Recipient. The videos are stored as an NSOrderedSet. when using

Edit: This is the declaration of the NSFetchedResultsController

```
  lazy var fetchedRC: NSFetchedResultsController<Recipient> = {
    let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<Recipient> = Recipient.fetchRequest()

    let reversedDescriptor = dateSortDescriptor.reversedSortDescriptor as! NSSortDescriptor


    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [dateSortDescriptor]

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext:managedContext , sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

   fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

    return fetchedResultsController
}()
```

Edit: Meant to post this method.

```
 func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {

    switch type {
    case .insert:
        print("I inserted")
        break;
    case .delete:
        print("I deleted")
        break;
    case . update:
        print("I updated")
        break;
    default:
        print("I don't know")
    }


}
```

It always returns I don't know even though a change is detected.

```
  let selectedPerson = personsArray[cellSelected] as? Recipient

    guard let currentContext = selectedPerson?.managedObjectContext else {
        print("I AM NOT SET")
        return
    }

    let video = Videos(context: currentContext)
    video.thumbNail = savedImageData
    video.urlPath = url
    video.isVideo = true
    video.isVoiceMemo = false
    video.isWrittenMemo = false
    video.uuID = uuid
    video.creationDate = NSDate()


    if let videos = selectedPerson?.videos?.mutableCopy() as? NSMutableOrderedSet {
        videos.add(video)
        selectedPerson?.latestMemoDate = NSDate()
        selectedPerson?.videos = videos
    }
        do {

        try selectedPerson?.managedObjectContext?.save()
        try video.managedObjectContext?.save()
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
```

Comment: Can you paste the code for creating `NSFetchedResultsController`. Only changes relevant (that would affect) to the fetched results controller predicate / sort descriptor would be detected. Also make sure the delegate for the fetched results controller is set

Comment: I edited the post to show what you asked

Comment: Your didChange delegate method does not have a `case` for the `.move` change type, so it falls through to the `default` clause.  I guess your sortDescriptor must be based on the latestMemoDate, so when you add the video, and update the latestMemoDate, the FRC sees that as a move event for the Recipient.  Hence you need to add a case for .move.

Comment: you got it! When adding the cases I didn't see that one on accident I guess. Thanks!